# Not able to install WebSphere setup.exe using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, ibm-mq

By using the below code I am able to download zip file from web, then unzip it into a folder, then go to Windows folder → `setup.exe`. I am able to double click on `setup.exe` but I am not able to do silent installation or click OK/Next on the installation interface.

[image]

PowerShell code:

```bsh
if ($installationItem.FeatureName -match "WebSphere-Features") {
    # if software directory not exists then create it
    if (!(Test-Path $installationItem.FolderPath)) {
          New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $installationItem.FolderPath | Out-Null
    }

    Write-Host "Downloading WebSphere... "

    $client.DownloadFile($installationItem.Source, $installationItem.FilePath)
    if (!(Test-Path $installationItem.FilePath)) {
        Write-Host "Downloading $installationItem.FilePath failed"
        return
    }

    Expand-Archive -Force -Path $installationItem.FilePath -DestinationPath  $installationItem.FolderPath
    # check if websphere already installed
    if (Test-Path $installationItem.Test_Path) {
        Write-Host 'Websphere Already Installed ..Skipping installtion of websphere.'
        return
    } else {
        # Provide full access to the executable file to run
        Unblock-File -Path $installationItem.FilePath1

        # process installation
        $proc1 = Start-Process -FilePath $installationItem.FilePath1 -ArgumentList "/s /v /qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress" -Wait -PassThru -Verb "RunAs"

        $proc1.WaitForExit()
```

`setting.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<InstallationManagement>
    <Installation Name="WebSphere" FeatureName="WebSphere-Features" Source="https://path/ibm_webshpere-1.zip" FolderPath="C:\softwares\websphere" FilePath="C:\softwares\ibm_webshpere-1.zip" FilePath1="C:\softwares\websphere\Windows\Setup.exe" Test_Path="C:\Program Files\webshpere"></Installation>   
</InstallationManagement>
```

Please help in the silent installation of websphere or interacting the interface of the installation window.

Comment: `-ArgumentList "/s /v /qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress"` -> `-ArgumentList '/s /v"/qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress"'`?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thanks for the response  . but i am stillgetting the "IBM WebSphere MQ - InstallShield Wizard "  window by trying both the ways

Comment: Then try `-ArgumentList '-s -a /s /v"/qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress"'`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers still the same issue :( . note : i tried the same command for jave.exe it worked but not working for websphere,

Comment: Are you trying to install the server or a client? The server installation might need an answer file from what I've read. [SuperUser](https//superuser.com/) would be a more fitting place for this type of question, though.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I am trying to installing client .